# trying to fill a new column in a dataframe with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Based on a value of another column I'd like to fill out a new column with a for loop. Regrettably not getting the results I need;

```
profit = []

# For each row in the column,
for row in df3['Result']:
    # if value is;
    if row == 'H':
        # Append a Profit/Loss
        profit.append(df3['column value H'])
    # else, if value is,
    elif row == 'D':
        # Append a Profit/Loss
        profit.append(df3['column value D'])        
    # otherwise,
    else:
        # Append a Profit/Loss
        profit.append(df3['column value A'])

df3['profit'] = profit
```

Comment: Please show ```df3.head()``` - if there aren't too many columns. - and your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df3['profit'] = np.where(df3['Result'] == 'H', df3['column value H'], 
                np.where(df3['Result'] == 'D', df3['column value D'], df3['column value A']))
```

Sample:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Result':['H','D','E'],
                   'column value H':[4,5,6],
                   'column value D':[7,8,9],
                   'column value A':[1,3,5]})

print (df3)
  Result  column value A  column value D  column value H
0      H               1               7               4
1      D               3               8               5
2      E               5               9               6

df3['profit'] = np.where(df3['Result'] == 'H', df3['column value H'], 
                np.where(df3['Result'] == 'D', df3['column value D'], df3['column value A']))

print (df3)
  Result  column value A  column value D  column value H  profit
0      H               1               7               4       4
1      D               3               8               5       8
2      E               5               9               6       5
```

**Timings**:

```
In [198]: %timeit (jez(df3))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.59 ms per loop

In [199]: %timeit (wwii(df4))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.49 s per loop

In [200]: %timeit (wwii1(df5))
1 loop, best of 3: 4.48 s per loop
```

**Code for testing**:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Result':['H','D','E'],
                   'column value H':[4,5,6],
                   'column value D':[7,8,9],
                   'column value A':[1,3,5]})

print (df3)
df3 = pd.concat([df3]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

df4 = df3.copy()
df5 = df3.copy()

def jez(df3):
    df3['profit'] = np.where(df3['Result'] == 'H', df3['column value H'], 
                    np.where(df3['Result'] == 'D', df3['column value D'], df3['column value A']))

    return (df3)

def foo(series):
    # d maps Result column values to DataFrame/Series column names
    d = {'H':'column value H', 'D':'column value D'}
    try:
        return series[d[series['Result']]]
    except KeyError as e:
        return series['column value A']

def wwii(df3):
    df3['Profit'] = df3.apply(foo, axis = 1)
    return df3

def wwii1(df3):
    profit = []
    for row in df3.iterrows():
        series = row[1]
        if series.Result == 'H':
            # Append a Profit/Loss
            profit.append(series['column value H'])
        # else, if value is,
        elif series.Result == 'D':
            # Append a Profit/Loss
            profit.append(series['column value D'])
        # otherwise,
        else:
            # Append a Profit/Loss
            profit.append(series['column value A'])

    df3['profit'] = profit        
    return df3            

print (jez(df3))    
print (wwii(df4))    
print (wwii1(df5))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, as do the other 2 solutions. Which one would I prefer if have additional calculations to perform?

Comment: btw, I've timed them and there is not much difference between them.

Comment: If use larger dataframe e.g. `30k` rows, `numpy.where` solution is the fastest. Is small DataFrame maybe difference is small.

Comment: Do you think  if not `H` then `-1` ? `df['profit'] = np.where(df3['Result'] == 'H', df3['column value H'], -1`) ?

Comment: exactly, tried it already, but got an error. forgot a parenthesis.... thanks anyway

Comment: super, you can upvote this answer if you want, thanks.

Comment: I have another question regarding this solution. if I want to add in another condition, i.e.:
if column H > column A and 'Result' == 'H', return column H, 
if column H < column A and 'Result' == 'A', return column 'A', 
if either is not true, return -1

Comment: Please check `df3['profit'] = np.where((df3['Result'] == 'H') & (df3['column value H'] > df3['column value A']), df3['column value H'], 
                 np.where((df3['Result'] == 'A') & (df3['column value H'] < df3['column value A']), df3['column value A'], -1))
`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any row information in your operations.  As you probably noticed, `df3['column value H']` returns a series instead of a singe value for the row you want to operate on.

To fix your for loop use [DataFrame.iterrows()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) which returns (index, series) tuples for each row. Then you can access each column in the row with `series['column name']`.

```
for row in df3.iterrows():
    series = row[1]
    if series.Result == 'H':
        # Append a Profit/Loss
        profit.append(series['column value H'])
    # else, if value is,
    elif series.Result == 'D':
        # Append a Profit/Loss
        profit.append(series['column value D'])        
    # otherwise,
    else:
        # Append a Profit/Loss
        profit.append(series['column value A'])
```

---

Another option is to write a function that takes a series as an argument, processes it and returns the value you want.  Then use [DataFrame.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) - specify `axis = 1` to apply the function over rows.

```
def foo(series):
    # d maps Result column values to DataFrame/Series column names
    d = {'H':'column value H', 'D':'column value D'}
    try:
        return series[d[series['Result']]]
    except KeyError as e:
        return series['column value A']

df3['Profit'] = df3.apply(foo, axis = 1)
```

---

The [double where proposed by @jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40636661/2823755) might be best if the DataFrame isn't any more complicated than presumed (no example given) but if there are more possible columns or more conditions, it could get messy.